# Python - xlwings list all named ranges/macros

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am trying to find all the macros in an excel workbook through xlwings. Is there a way to list all the named ranges/macros using xlwings? I found the documentation talking about names as a collection, but I am unfamiliar on how to use it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
wb = xw.Book("MyBook.xlsx")
for name in wb.names:
    print(name)
```